# Mongodb compound index is not in use with query

Tags: mongodb, indexing, compound-index

Hi can somebody explain me please how to make compound index for this simple query?

```
find({
    "userId":{"$in":["5c778c4f52732c06d3384269","5b274b672a35d168960b1bd5","5bc43d6552732c527345c35d","58ec836e899753a22b95fb19"]},
    "end":{"$gte": ISODate('2019-05-03 11:05:00+02:00')}
})
```

I have done two compound indexes:

1. userId: 1 + end: 1
2. userId: 1 + end: -1

but query does not use any of them. What is wrong with this indexes?

Here is the result of explain()

```
{
    "queryPlanner": {
        "plannerVersion": 1,
        "namespace": "WebApp.SessionLog",
        "indexFilterSet": false,
        "parsedQuery": {
            "$and": [
                {
                    "end": {
                        "$gte": ISODate("2019-05-03T07:05:00Z")
                    }
                },
                {
                    "userId": {
                        "$in": [
                            "58ec836e899753a22b95fb19",
                            "5b274b672a35d168960b1bd5",
                            "5bc43d6552732c527345c35d",
                            "5c778c4f52732c06d3384269"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan": {
            "stage": "FETCH",
            "filter": {
                "userId": {
                    "$in": [
                        "58ec836e899753a22b95fb19",
                        "5b274b672a35d168960b1bd5",
                        "5bc43d6552732c527345c35d",
                        "5c778c4f52732c06d3384269"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "inputStage": {
                "stage": "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern": {
                    "end": -1
                },
                "indexName": "end",
                "isMultiKey": false,
                "multiKeyPaths": {
                    "end": []
                },
                "isUnique": false,
                "isSparse": false,
                "isPartial": false,
                "indexVersion": 2,
                "direction": "forward",
                "indexBounds": {
                    "end": [
                        "[new Date(9223372036854775807), new Date(1556867100000)]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans": [
            {
                "stage": "FETCH",
                "inputStage": {
                    "stage": "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern": {
                        "userId": 1,
                        "end": -1
                    },
                    "indexName": "userId_1_end_-1",
                    "isMultiKey": false,
                    "multiKeyPaths": {
                        "userId": [],
                        "end": []
                    },
                    "isUnique": false,
                    "isSparse": false,
                    "isPartial": false,
                    "indexVersion": 2,
                    "direction": "forward",
                    "indexBounds": {
                        "userId": [
                            "[\"58ec836e899753a22b95fb19\", \"58ec836e899753a22b95fb19\"]",
                            "[\"5b274b672a35d168960b1bd5\", \"5b274b672a35d168960b1bd5\"]",
                            "[\"5bc43d6552732c527345c35d\", \"5bc43d6552732c527345c35d\"]",
                            "[\"5c778c4f52732c06d3384269\", \"5c778c4f52732c06d3384269\"]"
                        ],
                        "end": [
                            "[new Date(9223372036854775807), new Date(1556867100000)]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "stage": "FETCH",
                "inputStage": {
                    "stage": "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern": {
                        "userId": 1,
                        "end": 1
                    },
                    "indexName": "userId_1_end_1",
                    "isMultiKey": false,
                    "multiKeyPaths": {
                        "userId": [],
                        "end": []
                    },
                    "isUnique": false,
                    "isSparse": false,
                    "isPartial": false,
                    "indexVersion": 2,
                    "direction": "forward",
                    "indexBounds": {
                        "userId": [
                            "[\"58ec836e899753a22b95fb19\", \"58ec836e899753a22b95fb19\"]",
                            "[\"5b274b672a35d168960b1bd5\", \"5b274b672a35d168960b1bd5\"]",
                            "[\"5bc43d6552732c527345c35d\", \"5bc43d6552732c527345c35d\"]",
                            "[\"5c778c4f52732c06d3384269\", \"5c778c4f52732c06d3384269\"]"
                        ],
                        "end": [
                            "[new Date(1556867100000), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "stage": "FETCH",
                "filter": {
                    "end": {
                        "$gte": ISODate("2019-05-03T07:05:00Z")
                    }
                },
                "inputStage": {
                    "stage": "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern": {
                        "userId": 1
                    },
                    "indexName": "userId",
                    "isMultiKey": false,
                    "multiKeyPaths": {
                        "userId": []
                    },
                    "isUnique": false,
                    "isSparse": false,
                    "isPartial": false,
                    "indexVersion": 2,
                    "direction": "forward",
                    "indexBounds": {
                        "userId": [
                            "[\"58ec836e899753a22b95fb19\", \"58ec836e899753a22b95fb19\"]",
                            "[\"5b274b672a35d168960b1bd5\", \"5b274b672a35d168960b1bd5\"]",
                            "[\"5bc43d6552732c527345c35d\", \"5bc43d6552732c527345c35d\"]",
                            "[\"5c778c4f52732c06d3384269\", \"5c778c4f52732c06d3384269\"]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "serverInfo": {
        "host": "mongo1",
        "port": 9000,
        "version": "3.4.2",
        "gitVersion": "3f76e40c105fc223b3e5aac3e20dcd026b83b38b"
    },
    "ok": 1
}
```

here is the documents example:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("56c49c147569943e7d4e92f4"),
    "ip": "213.81.143.50",
    "count": 17,
    "end": ISODate("2014-12-02T08:39:56Z"),
    "userId": "546dda33899753840584752b",
    "date": ISODate("2014-12-02T08:36:47Z"),
    "logs": [
        {
            "parameters": {
                "action": "dashboard",
                "id": null,
                "package": ""
            },
            "ip": "213.81.143.50",
            "date": ISODate("2014-12-02T08:36:47Z"),
            "presenter": "Dashboard",
            "action": "dashboard"
        },
        {
            "parameters": {
                "action": "dashboard",
                "id": null,
                "backlink": ""
            },
            "ip": "213.81.143.50",
            "date": ISODate("2014-12-02T08:36:48Z"),
            "presenter": "Dashboard",
            "action": "dashboard"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks.

PS: This PS text is only for Stackoverflow editor error.

Comment: Please add an example document and the result of [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/).

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: It must be related to userId cardinality. It works as you expect on data generated as `{"end": {"$date": {"min": "2014-01-01", "max": "2019-01-01"}}, "userId": {$hash:{length: 24}}}`, and it uses only date index on data generated as `{"end": {"$date": {"min": "2014-01-01", "max": "2019-01-01"}}, "userId": {"$choose": {"from": ["58ec836e899753a22b95fb19", "5b274b672a35d168960b1bd5", "5bc43d6552732c527345c35d", "5c778c4f52732c06d3384269"]}}}}` which is a good thing since userId filter is not quite selective. Try to hint the index to check if the compound one is any faster.

Answer (score 0):

In query explain result you can see "indexName": "end" under `winningPlan`.
This mean your query used index with `end` name.

Comment: Yes I know. But there is compound index why Mongodb does not use it?

Comment: this one more preferable for mongo.

Comment: can you send indexes info (for this collection)

Comment: @andranikasl indices info is in the explain result - the second snippet in the question.